# rar file module not working in python 2.7

Tags: python

i have a code like this

```
import rarfile
pwd = None
rar = rarfile.RarFile(source_filename)
rar.extractall(dest_dir,None,pwd)  # error from here
```

this code in working in ubuntu.
when i run this on windows i get error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1_bete_rar.pyw", line 132, in extract
  File "1_bete_rar.pyw", line 176, in unrar_file
  File "rarfile.pyc", line 586, in extractall
  File "rarfile.pyc", line 1112, in _extract
  File "rarfile.pyc", line 1704, in custom_popen
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 711, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 948, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

what is the problem with my code? how can i extract rar file with python in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [`rarfile` FAQ](https://rarfile.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) states (and as is made evident by traces of `subprocess` in the stack trace),

> [rarfile] depends on unrar command-line utility to do the actual decompression.
>
> Note that by default it expect it to be in PATH. If unrar launching fails, you need to fix this.

So get UnRAR from http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm and put it somewhere in your PATH (such as the directory you're running your script from).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `source_filename` isn't pointing to a valid RAR file, do this little check before, just to be sure:

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(source_filename) # what's the value returned?
```

If the file exists, then check if the path is in the correct format. For example, this won't work:

```
source_filename = 'c:\documents\file.rar'
```

Try this instead:

```
source_filename = 'c:\\documents\\file.rar'
```

Or even better, use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
source_filename = r'c:\documents\file.rar'
```

Comment: @user2602709 looks like a problem with the path format. Could you post here in a comment the contents of the `source_filename` variable?

Answer (score 0):

One common problem using python with Windows is that the path separator is \, but this is a special character that needs to be escaped in Python. If you print the source_filename you should be able to see if this is set correctly.

e.g.

```
source_filename = 'c:\users\prosserc\documents\myfile.txt'
```

will not work correctly. Here are a couple of alternatives:

Use a raw string:

```
source_filename = r'c:\users\prosserc\documents\myfile.txt'
```

or use os.path.join to join to an eviornment variable such as user_profile

```
source_filename = os.path.join(os.getenv('userprofile'), 'documents', 'myfile.txt')
```